# Lua - table length seems invalid

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
a = {}
a[1] = 1
a[2] = nil -- does nothing, as a[2] is already nil
a[3] = 14

print(#a)
```

prints 1

```
a = {}
a[1] = 1
a[2] = nil -- does nothing, as a[2] is already nil
a[3] = 14
a[4] = 5

print(#a)
```

prints 4

What does the # operator really return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table is not a proper sequence, the return value of the `#` operator applied to that table is undefined.

In both of your cases, `a` is not a proper sequence because `a[2] == nil` and `a[3] ~= nil`.

The `#` operator returns the length of proper sequences.